# Conditional probability in three-way Contingency table

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, contingency-tables

[image]

If I wanted to find $P(\gamma = yes \mid \beta = A, \alpha = no)$, would this simply be $\frac{X_5}{X_5+X_6}$?

Comment: yes (additional characters in order to comment).

Comment: It depends on what "find" might mean.  If this table is intended as a mathematical description of ("find") a probability distribution, the answer is "yes." Otherwise, if it reflects data from a random sample, then you cannot uncover ("find") the true underlying probability: you can only adopt a model for it and estimate it.  There is a standard model--namely, the probabilities don't change from observation to observation--but there are many different ways to *estimate* ("find") those probabilities.